# Check if any row of the group by is empty

Tags: php, group-by

I am checking all rows of the `group by` `$b`, In-case of empty row in `$b` I want to disable the button of group column `$a`, as in the following script. And I am using `group by` that's why it is only working on the first row of `$b`.
How to disable button of a group column if any of it row is empty?
And should I use loop to check all the rows of `$b`.

**PHP**

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
        $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT a, b from table  WHERE id = :id group by a");
        $sql ->bindparam(':id',$id);
        $sql ->execute();   
        while($row = $sql ->fetch(PDO:: FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
                $a = $row['a'];
                $b = $row['b'];
                if(!empty ($b))
                    {
                        echo '<tr>
                        <td><input type="button" name="a[]" value="'.$a.'"></td>
                        </tr>';
                    }else{
                        echo '<tr>
                        <td><input type="button" name="a[]" value="'.$a.'" disabled></td>
                        </tr>';
                    }

        } // while
```

Comment: Do a `var_dump()` of `$c` and see if it is ever `empty`.

Comment: @ChukwuemekaInya Yes  I have checked it, `$c` have 1 empty row, But its not disabling button.

Comment: Ok... Instead of trying to disable, can you just `echo` a string...Let's see if that condition will even run.

Comment: @ChukwuemekaInya Yes it do, And when i remove `group by` from query, then it fetches several buttons And disabling the button which have empty value. But by adding `group by` its not working.

Comment: Since you're not aggregating any data, I'm not sure why you're adding `group by` to this query? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Your query is incorrect from the start. You should not have a SELECT with different columns as in your GROUP BY. You SELECT `a, b, c` and you GROUP BY `a` only. It is illogical and not allowed in standard SQL. Please explain clearly what you are trying to do

Comment: To expand on my previous comment : Your query only works because you are in an old version of MySQL or because you have disabled the option [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)

Comment: @ThomasG If i `SELECT a, b, c and GROUP BY d` then is it ok? because d have the same value for all a,b, and c

Comment: NO. You should have the same columns in the SELECT and the GROUP BY. The only reason to GROUP BY is to have aggregate functions in the SELECT which is not your case. Theres probably a way to achieve what you want in SQL, but I really dont understand what you want and seeing all the unaccepted answers below, I am not alone. Your question is unclear: please edit it, rephrase everything correctly and give proper details, and only then you will receive a correct answer.

Comment: @Nick i am using group by to group it on the same value because they have the same value in multiple rows.

Comment: @Nick  have a look at the update in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to check for each team if there is at least one result null,
try this sql line :

```
SELECT `team_id`, `team`, MIN(IFNULL(`result`, -1)) `result`
FROM `teams` 
WHERE `group_id` = :id
GROUP BY `team_id`
```

**IFNULL(`result`, -1)** will return result if result not null and **-1** if it is null

Therefore **MIN(IFNULL(`result`, -1))** will return the minimum value of all result of the team, and if there is a null result, it will return **-1**

Therefore, the rest is pretty simple:

```
foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $row) {
    $a = $row['team'];
    $b = $row['result'];
    if ($b < 0) {
        // disable case
    } else {
        // enable case
    }
}
```

NB1: I assumed that results cannot be negative, if this is not the case, use ABS function.

NB2: it's always better to work with indexes than a name in transnational databases.

Answer (score 0):

First add `ORDER BY` on your `$sql`

```
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT a, b FROM `table` WHERE id = :id GROUP BY a ORDER BY b IS NULL, b ASC");
```

> In MySQL NULL values are considered lower in order than any non-NULL
>   value

Useful Reference : [Here](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-order-null-values-first-or-last-in-mysql#sort-in-ascending-order-with-nulls-last)

Comment: generated this error  `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY a' at line 1 `

Comment: Check out my updated code above, I just removed the white spaces and change order of clauses and `table` is an reserved word in sql so I enclose it with backticks. Thanks

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/join-syntax/ is the actual reference here... while there might be no `JOIN` possible with a single table, therefore it is not required/possible to `GROUP BY`... for unique values it is `SELECT DISTINCT` (which behaves alike `GROUP BY` without a `JOIN` on another table).

Comment: try changing `ORDER BY -c DESC` to `ORDER BY c IS NULL, c ASC`

Comment: Saw your updated question, Check out my updated code above. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

the condition is: `( is_null($c) ? ' disabled' : '')`

which means: if `$c` is `NULL`, return the string `_disabled`.

in context:

```
echo '<tr>
    <td><input type="button" name="a[]" value="'.$a.'"'.( is_null($c) ? ' disabled' : '').'></td>
    <td><input type="button" name="b[]" value="'.$b.'"'.( is_null($c) ? ' disabled' : '').'></td>
</tr>';
```

Comment: No, I want to check the number of rows of $c only. To check if there is any empty row in this column.

Comment: @SamDasti that would be `if(! is_null($c))`... just use `$result = $sql->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); die('<pre>'.print_r($result, true).'</pre>');` to see, what is even being returned as the result-set. it is not exactly a difficult question, but it is difficult to answer while not knowing that. hope this helps.

Comment: it gives only first row because of `group by` And i want all rows to be checked.

Comment: can i group it out of query. that way I will be able to check all rows first and then group it.

Comment: @SamDasti you can simply check with `IS_NULL()` function, in the `SQL` statement already: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/is-null-optimization.html
eg. `WHERE NOT IS_NULL(c)`

Comment: I want to display all but incase of  empty row of c it should be disabled.

Comment: @SamDasti in your code, there only is button `a` and button `b` ...updated the above code to disable them, when field `c` is null. also see the comment above; the `GROUP BY` either needs a `JOIN` or should be removed. is that more likely now?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (works in mine):

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
define('DBINFO', 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourdatabasehere');
define('DBUSER','root');
define('DBPASS','');
$con = new PDO(DBINFO, DBUSER, DBPASS);
$query = "SELECT team,result from teams  WHERE id = '$id' group by team";
$stmt = $con->query($query);
foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $row):
    $a = $row['team'];
    $b = $row['result'];
    if(!empty ($b)):
?>
      <tr>
      <td><input type="button" name="a[]" value="<?= $a ?>"></td>
      </tr>
<?php
    else:
 ?>
       <tr>
       <td><input type="button" name="a[]" value="<?= $a ?>" disabled></td>
       </tr>
<?php
    endif;
endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: If we fetch data of `group_id =23` as in the above table and then if the result of `Deno` is empty then its disabling team B button otherwise if  Skion and Niob's is empty then its not disabling its button (Team B).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to disable button of a Team who has null `Result` value in any row.

So, If here you are using Group By on column `a` only and you want to iterate over all values of `b` for null check, You need to use an aggregate function over `b`.

Try using below query:

```
SELECT a, MIN(IF(b IS NULL or b = '', -1, b)) b_val FROM teams WHERE group_id = :id GROUP BY a
```

Here, if any row of your example has value of Result as Null, then `b_val=-1` will be returned for that group instead of the values 55, 14, 26, etc..

Your If condition `if(!empty ($b))` will change to : `if($b!=-1)`

Comment: then should i write `$b = $row['b_val'];` .

Comment: this way its disabling all buttons,both empty and non empty.

Comment: Yes, `$b = $row['b_val']`;

Comment: You may have to change your `if` condition too as per above.